# Prevent codecoverage print to console

Tags: python, code-coverage

I'm new to Coverage.py and to Python also.

I'm generating a combined report from individual python scripts using

```
os.system("coverage combine")
os.system("coverage report -m")
os.system("coverage xml")
```

I'm trying to write the Coverage report output printed on console to a .txt file insted. I don't want the console output printed. Is there a way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm generating a combined report from individual python scripts usingos.system("coverage combine")
                os.system("coverage report -m")
                os.system("coverage xml")'

Comment: I'm afraid I must use the shelling-out to the executable. I noticed that if I exclude `os.system("coverage report -m")` there is no console output. However I need that output - but in a txt file

Comment: Why do you need to use os.system? Coverage.py has an API you can call from Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already shelling-out using `os.system`, you can leverage the shell and simply redirect the output to a text file:

```
os.system("coverage report -m > cov.txt")
```

That said, since you're using Python to drive this process, you should consider doing it directly from Python, starting with

```
import coverage
```